# Bumped Questions

Tags: discussion

The community bot is bumping old questions to the homepage - is this really useful?

For example this question will probably never get an answer and was bumped to the top more than once (if I'm not mistaken but I'm quite sure I've seen it before):

[What is causing my cursor to look so strange?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6793/what-is-causing-my-cursor-to-look-so-strange)

Answer (score 3):

I find it of questionable utility, however, sometimes, just once in a while, a bumped question does get a good answer from the bumping. And sometimes you see a bumped question which you realise should be closed. ... Like I'm going to close that one, since Carpetsmoker's comment on debugging vimrc doesn't appear to have been acted on, which leaves us without enough information.

Comment: It's a shame that the OP never replied, since the question accumulated votes of a period of months, probably meaning that people having the same problem end up here in search of an answer :-/

Comment: Isn't that what 'Unanswered' is for? Here's another one: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8939/easygrep-plugin-is-there-a-way-to-search-only-the-current-buffer

Comment: @laktak people tend to use the Active page more than Unanswered. For this one, it no longer counts as unanswered, now that it has an upvoted answer. However, you can provide an answer for it from https://github.com/dkprice/vim-easygrep/issues/38#issuecomment-249416764 if you feel like it.